# UIAlertController – way to get views for message and actions?

Tags: objective-c, layout, accessibility, vertical-alignment, ios12

We need to use a `UITextView` (i.e. multi-line text entry) to allow the user to enter information. `UITextView` doesn't work nicely with autoresize, so we set the constraints using the boundaries of the `UIAlertController` view. There are layout issues depending on accessibility settings.

For example, this a layout, nice and neat, under larger text settings:

[image]

But using the same constraints, this is what it looks like using default text settings:

[image]

Not good! We don't want to get into the rabbit hole of customizing code for each model and text size settings. Is there a legal way to get the views for the message and actions so that we can align to these features instead?

"Legal" because the official documentation for `UIAlertController` indicates (*emphasis* mine):

> **Important**
>
> The `UIAlertController` class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The *view hierarchy for this class is private* and must not be modified.

And have confirmed that the actions (the `Cancel` and `Submit` buttons) don't seem to be visible when we're iterating through `[[alertController view] subviews]`, so we have to be careful here.

Also, `safeAreaInsets` is `{0, 0, 0, 0}` for all iPhone models, so that's not any help here.

I guess most of the problem is from the stacking of the buttons, so if there is a way to detect that configuration, that would fix most of the layout issue.

It's an older app, so we're coding in Objective-C, but Swift solutions are okay too.

Comment: To get a consistent appearance using a `UITextView` in that way, your best bet is to create your own view controller and present it modally. Use Delegate / Protocol pattern to communicate back to the presenting controller (which button was tapped, the content of the text view, etc).

Comment: The correct solution is to not use `UIAlertController`. Write (or find) a custom alert that properly supports using a text view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @DonMag and @rmaddy for your suggestions, but the budget allows for us only to revise the existing `UIAlertController` code, as opposed to creating a new view controller.

We reviewed the issue and found that there were only three cases we needed to worry about, specifically the `XL`, `XXL`, and `XXXL` preferred content size categories. We handled them directly:

```
NSString *sizeCategory = UIScreen.mainScreen.traitCollection.preferredContentSizeCategory;
CGFloat top = -82.f;
CGFloat bottom = +52.0f;
if ([sizeCategory isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryExtraLarge])
{
    top = -90.0f;
    bottom = +98.0f;
}
else if ([sizeCategory isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryExtraExtraLarge])
{
    top = -118.0f;
    bottom = +98.0f;
}
else if ([sizeCategory isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryExtraExtraExtraLarge])
{
    top = -160.0f;
    bottom = +98.0f;
}
```

Then the code to set up the constraints follows after this. The code already has hard-coded constants, so we aren't making the situation too much worse!

We aren't handling the additional text sizes under "Larger Accessibility Sizes" at this time. The app in general requires a minimum level of visual acuity.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the proper method from UiKit, **addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler**:
As an example:

```
-(void)showAlert{
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Defining by Words Only" message:@"Enter the words you want to use,separated by spaces." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Submit Words" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
[self submitWordsMethods:alert.textFields.firstObject.text];}];
    UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];

    //Doesn't allow to send a empty answer.
    [alert addAction: action];
    [action setEnabled:NO];
    [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * _Nonnull textField) {
        //Text field activates el boton de enviar cuando tiene texto.
        [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(alertControllerTextFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    }];
    [alert addAction: cancel];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**This is the result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but specific requirements were for a text view as opposed to a text field, which as you noted above, are **much** easier!